# how to apply the md5 in a ajax variable

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a code that suppose receive an ajax variable and i want to apply the md5 before to send on database how can i make the variable received by the script become encrypt with md5 before to send on database?
the variable it receive by ajax is $points

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

if(isset($_GET['points'])){

     //Lightly sanitize the GET's to prevent SQL injections and possible XSS attacks

     $points = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['points']));
    //$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `publiadd_loginsx`.`users` (`points`) VALUES ('points');");
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points +'$points' WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);

     if($sql){
          //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
          echo 'Your Points was saved. Congrats!';
     }else{
          //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
          echo 'There was a problem saving your points. Please try again later.';
     }
}else{
     echo 'Your points wasnt passed in the request. Make sure you add ?name=NAME_HERE&score=1337 to the tags.';
}

// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do realise that if you hash `points`, as that is what MD5 is, you will never be able to unhash then. Also `SET user_points = user_points +'$points'` will never work again

Comment: Could you provide a little context on what you're attempting to achieve. What are you attempting to use MD5 to achieve? MD5 isn't used for encryption but for hashing. If you're trying to ensure that a user cannot update their points by changing the value they pass in points you need to consider a completely different way of handling it on the service side rather than the client side.

Comment: well yes what i search is to difficult the users to update they points pass there on ajax call variable

Comment: bgcolor? wow are you still using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_* is deprecated and insecure use pdo instead.

md5 is a hash alogithm and can not be used to encrypt/decrypt only for validation

encryption will not secure anything caus the user/browser will do it and send it to the server. so they keys used for encryptions are known.

why the score/points are userside calculated? just transmit the result of the task or whatever and calculate the points if the answer or whatever is correct.
everything browserside(ajax) is reproducable by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain well your context, but if you want a little security you can update user's points using `POST` call instead with `<form action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post"></form>`.

As other developers say MD5 can't be decrypting. If you want to proceed with this method sent value `X` and `md5(X)` to the server and then check with PHP if both MD5 values are equals.